# Could liquid ventilation offer more effective treatment for pneumonia?

Tags: covid-19, pneumonia, mechanical-ventilation, liquids

Thinking about pneumonia as the cause of death for COVID-19 victims, it seems natural to wonder - why not fight fluid with fluid?

Breathing in oxygen through liquid [is possible](https://www.realclearscience.com/blog/2019/08/15/can_humans_breathe_liquid.html). Although it seems more research is needed to determine its effectiveness as a treatment.

Examples of medical research on liquid ventilation:

[Liquid ventilation (2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4258983/)

[Initial experience with partial liquid ventilation in adult patients with the acute respiratory distress syndrome (1996)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8569018/)

Although it is most likely too late to deploy liquid ventilation to combat the present pandemic, is there evidence that indicates liquid ventilation could be a more effective treatment for pneumonia than traditional ventilation?

There is a lot of interesting information in the 2014 paper, but I don't have the backgroung to know how to interpret the findings and compare the effectiveness to traditional ventilation. That's why I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest data on using Partial Liquid Ventilation (Total Liquid Ventilation has been shown to be unsustainable) was from a 1996 study

> Hirschl et al. treated 10 adults who had acute respiratory distress syndrome (ARDS) and reported a decrease in the physiologic shunt and an increase in pulmonary compliance; 50% of the patients survived in their study. Based on their clinical experiences, they concluded that PLV may be associated with observed improvements in gas exchange and pulmonary compliance.[15]

There is no data on the use of PLV in adults with ARDS from Covid-19, and the use of PLV in that very tiny study doesn't seem to offer any advantage over standard ventilation in terms of survival.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3191624/